# Pivot table shows all 12 months in every quarter

Tags: excel, date, pivot

When creating a pivot table form my dataset, I need to show the years the quarters and the months to see the data related to the dates. But when I expand the entries, every quarter shows all 12 months (eg. in Q1 I can see the months showing from Jan to Dec). I cannot untick the "Show items with no data" option because I need to show later in a graph every month where no data was added as well, so it is necessary. Do you know why this issue is happening? I tried changing the data types already.

pivot_quarter_month_error

[image]

I tried changing the date formats, double checked if there are dates that excel cannot identify, but noticed nothing. I want pivot to show only the related months in every quarter (eg. in Q1 only Jan, Feb, Mar; in Q2 only Apr, May, Jun; etc.)

Comment: Does [this](https://exceljet.net/pivot-tables/pivot-table-group-by-quarter) or [this](http://www.simplifiedexcel.com/2017/10/convert-dates-months-quarters-years-pivot-table/) help?

Comment: @PeterT unfortunately neither of those links helps me and I am experiencing the same problem as the OP.  Date grouping into Year/Quarter/Month has already been done using normal technique (as shown in one of those links), but when expanding the groups I see that each quarter has all 12 months under it (but data only shows for the 3 months relevant to the quarter). Any charts plotted using this pivot table have 75% empty space!